# how to get the column name of excel in php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

My column is increasing base on my test name ..how to take the test name from excel column .i want my excel header so i can save the result  with respective of test name in my database

here is my code

```
echo'<table width="80%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" align="center" border="1" class="table" id="temtable">
        <tr class="bold" style="color:#fff;background-color:#'.$_SESSION['tclr'].';" >
                            <th style="width:20px;">#</th>
                            <th>Name</th><th>Userid</th>';

 $test=$obj->listDirectQuery("SELECT  * FROM `evv`  WHERE status = '2'");   
$testnames=$obj->listDirectQuery("select id,test_name from test where id in(".$test[0]['tests'].")");   
                    foreach($testnames as $testname){ 
                            echo'<th>'.$testname['test_name'].'-('.$testname['id'].')</th>'; }
                            echo'</tr>'; 


                            $users=$obj->listDirectQuery("SELECT * from users where status = '2'");
                            $i=1;
                            foreach($users as $user){
                            echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td>';
                            echo '<td  style="text-align:center">'.$user['first_name'].''.$user['last_name'].'</td><td>'.$user["id"].'</td></tr>';$i++;
                            }
                            //echo'<td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">';



                            echo '</table>';
```

i am using  $insert_csv to get value of column. but how i will get test name wise

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `prescription` (user_id,test_id,test_results)VALUES(".$ids[0]['id'].",".$tid.",".$insert_csv['test_results'].",)";
```

`$tid` value i want to get which is in my excel header the test name which is dynamic according what test i have assigned

Comment: Do you want the database table header name in your excel file???

Comment: what are you looking for?

Comment: @A.ANoman i want my excel header so  i can save the result of result   with respective of test name in my database

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj i want my excel header so i can save the result with respective of test name in my database

Comment: @TaniyaChowdhury take a look on https://www.cloudways.com/blog/import-export-csv-using-php-and-mysql/ this link to learn about uploading csv file to mysql

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj ya i know this.but for you the excel header is static.for me its dynamic .and the header part also i need to store in database ..

Comment: so pick the first row alone as the dynamic header, instead of static header

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj how? 
I am using $insert_csv

Comment: may be try $insert_csv['test_results'][0] or $insert_csv['test_results'][1] @TaniyaChowdhury

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj ok will try and let you know